# mysql isn't joining data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I get the code to load the pages initially with sports, entertainment and want-ads but when i push the button i get all of the articles instead of the ones that correlate with the page chosen. What i would like to happen is when i push the sports button I get all of the articles related to sports (with no entertainment or want-ad articles).
I have a database with tables as follows:

TABLES ARE AS FOLLOWS:

```
PAGES-
pages.pageId(INT),
pages.pageTitle(VARCHAR),

ARTICLES-
articles.acrticleId(INT),
articles.articleTitle(VARCHAR),
articles.pageId(INT),

VIDEOS-
videos.videoId(INT),
videos.videoTitle(VARCHAR),
videos.videoLoc(VARCHAR),
videos.articlesId(INT),

IMAGES-
images.imageId(INT),
images.imageTitle(VARCHAR),
images.imageLoc(VARCHAR),
images.articlesId(INT),

TEXT-
text.textId(INT),
text.text(medium),
text.articlesId(INT),
```

I have a query that brings in all the pages with a while loop:

```
$sqlPAQuery = "SELECT pages.pageId, pages.pageTitle, articles.articleId, 
articles.articleTitle FROM pages, articles GROUP BY pages.pageTitle";
$paqueryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPAQuery);

while ($paqueryRow = mysqli_fetch_object($paqueryResult))
{

    $pages = "<a href = articles.php?pageId=".$paqueryRow->pageId." data-
    role='button' ><button id ='wrapper'>".$paqueryRow->pageTitle."</button>
    </a><br/><br/>";
    echo $pages;
}
```

when a button is pushed it brings in this query:

```
SELECT pages.pageId, pageTitle, articles.articleId, articles.articleTitle, 
GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle)
FROM articles join pages using (pageId)
GROUP BY pageId
```

the html/javascript to send the info is:

```
<div data-role="content" >
   <p>Is Nursing For You?</p>
    <br/>
        <div id = "div1" align="center"></div>
</div>




    </div> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#div1").load('FONWVhp.php', function() {
       $('#div1 a').button();
 });

$(document).on('click', '#div1 a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
       //   alert($(this).attr('href'));
        $("#div1").load(($(this).attr('href')), function() {
            $('#div1 a').button();
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#div1 a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert($(this).attr('href'));
        $("#div1").load(($(this).attr('href')), function() {
            $('#div1 a').button();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: All you need to do is filter your query with a `WHERE` statement.

Comment: not sure what to do with the WHERE clause: SELECT pages.pageId, pageTitle, articles.articleId, articles.articleTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle)
FROM articles join pages using (pageId) WHERE pages.pageId = articles.articleId
GROUP BY pageId

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your query a little bit, Just you have to do is to add where clause in it. Like this:

```
SELECT pages.pageId, pageTitle, articles.articleId, articles.articleTitle
FROM articles join pages using (pageId)
where pageId = 'current_page_id'
```

Comment: this helped but not the result it gives me one article instead of all the articles associated with that page:  SELECT pages.pageId, pageTitle, articles.articleId, articles.articleTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle)
FROM articles join pages using (pageId) WHERE pages.pageId =" .$_GET['pageId']."
GROUP BY pageId

Comment: you can make this where clause condition based. i.e., only append it in query when you need to show specific pageId data

Comment: yes you are right, you have to remove group by in this case.

Comment: I think the Where clause is tripping me up because i can only get one article instead of the entirety of all the articles associated with a particular page

Comment: no it's not where clause, it was group by clause. Try removing that in this particular case and you will get all the articles related to current page.